# A programming tool can deploy standalone software that can run in XP, win7 and win10

Tags: desktop-client

My client requires a software in portable HDD that can run in any windows pc he plugs in. Which will be better for this. I have heard about delphi once that has this capacity. Please recommend a better one. We will recruit that developer depending upon the best choice.

Comment: Why a "beter" one? What is wrong with Delphi?

Comment: No Delphi developer in our team and there are some limitations with delphi as far I know.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have anyone who can code? If not, you have quite a problem there. If you do then ask them to code in a language with which they are familiar.

Delphi has a [free eversion](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/starter), ***but*** 1) it doesn’t have database capability, 2) it only generates 232 bit, not 64 bit executable, and 3) you may not use it of your business makes US $1,00 or more profit each year.

There are hundreds of commonly used languages. If you don’t have a programmer, hire one. If you insist on doing it your self, a very popular and relatively easy to leanr language is Python. You shpoul duse the excelltn and free [Pycharm IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), community edition.

However, whichever language you choose, to make your program portable, do not write to the [Windows Registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry) , but use an [.Ini file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) if there program needs to store configuration data.

Comment: I'm a programmer. My team consists  c#, c++, vb.net, java, PHP programmers but there's no Delphi developer, I know some pascal which I learn a long ago. All the IDE i use here are purchased and legally activated, purchasing a new IDE will not be a problem, but it should satisfy our need. But What they required a solid desktop software, not web based. Problem with Delphi is the software they requires is definitely database based. I never have learned Python. 
But the concept you gave about making a software portable that's definitely a great idea. I will search for this. Thanks.

Comment: Most of my Delphi apps don't use a databse :-)  I think INI files are the main point here, all else is aside-issue. Why not continue to use C# (or even Java)?  (C++ is ***very*** similar to both).

Comment: This is absolutely a new issue to our team, providing a standalone app for multiple PCs. I knew there's only one IDE can deploy Standalone that's Delphi, but forgot about even never tried to make a software portable( which I saw with some pirated software or games. from your answer I recall the point of making the software portable, which we shall now test with C# or Java, which performs better with database, We will start the whole project for that. As it's a business software storing the data is major factor here. Thanks

Comment: "There's only one IDE can deploy Standalone that's Delphi" - I just don't understand that, sorry. It has nothing to do with the IDE. For the .EXE to be standalone, it should not access the registry. You can do that with any language. Of small data, like program configuration, use an .INI file.  For more data, it depends on the format; maybe a file, or maybe an Sqlite database, which is just a file and can be in the same directory on the removable media as the executable.

Comment: I agree about the registry and other issues brother, but working with IDE like Microsoft dot net that always requires dot net framework installed or Visual C++ requires c++ runtime installed. I saw delphi programs like cpuz that a single exe that can run in any PC regardless the OS. There company that requires software they don't want any installation issue for each pc. Just plug in and run. Tanks again.

Comment: Ah!! Now I understand what you mean (sorry). The obvious answer is to not use .NET, of course. If you want a freeware (near) equivalent to Delphi, then use http://www.lazarus-ide.org/ But you can also easilly code other languages  without .NET C++ for sure, Python too.

Comment: Don't forget to post and answer, to help future readers know what you used

Answer (score 1):

There is a Portable version of VirtualBox.  Requires admin rights on a machine you use it on (to load network stuff, etc) but then you can have a VM with whatever dev setup you want available.  Plug it in, launch the portable VirtualBox, start the guest machine with whatever OS+IDE+libs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Gupta Technologies **TeamDeveloper**](http://www.opentext.com/what-we-do/products/specialty-technologies/opentext-gupta-development-tools-databases/opentext-gupta-team-developer) (an OpenText subsidiary)  ( v7 just released ) , which is very similar, offering v. high performance and scalability.

Many driver options allow for easy integration with many 3rd Party databases. Or you can use Gupta's own SQLBase( v12 32bit or 64bit just released ) and be as inventive and complex, or a simple as you need.

•Maximizes code reusability over various deployment platforms.

•Applications can be Win32 OR Win64 API based desktop business applications
OR .NET WPF Desktop apps that interact exceptionally well with the .NET framework and other solutions

•Comprehensive set of well-designed data-aware UX Controls

•Powerful Report Builder for application-based reports and end user reporting and report customization.

•Rich data grid, including visual sorting, grouping, column filters and many useful cell types, such as hyperlinks, images, buttons, check boxes and more.

•Page Navigator for Microsoft® Outlook®-like apps.

•Many modern design themes for the user and developer to choose from.

•Fast and Easy Configuration and Deployment

•Integrate with Web Services-enabled solutions via REST services or XML Web Services. Connect your applications to software solutions providing REST APIs, such as SAP, SalesForce, OpenText AppWorks and others. Integrate Team Developer applications with your own service layer.

•Fast and easy to configure database drivers for Oracle, SQL Server, Sybase and OpenText Gupta SQLBase, ODBC, OLE DB and .NET Data Provider connectivity for all other databases.

•Includes SQLBase development database for easy development and application testing.

•Automatic code documentation features of Team Developer help developers document their code without having to manually write their documentation.
•Modern IDE for lightning speed database application development.

•Fast error-free coding using the Active Coding Assistant.

•Outline tabs for quick code navigation and excellent source overview.

•Color-coded outline structured source code allows to quickly understand source code.

•Integrated automated documentation tool.

•Many tools that help to increase developer productivity. For example, the orphaned code tool for detecting unused source code, the task tool for searching and managing tasks, the automated documentation tool and more.